# How to use foldM with a list of strings as accumulator? programming a NFA

Tags: list, haskell, monads, fold

I'm trying to get this NFA working, now it does very well the transition between a set (list) of states to another set of states. But when I try to use `foldM` (I will accept any other method too), I cant't because the type of `foldM` is `(Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b` and I want something like `(Foldable t, Monad m) => ([b] -> a -> m [b]) -> b -> t a -> m b`, if it's possible something like that. The main problem is in the function `testNFA`.

Here is the code:

```
-- NFA file format
-- 1st line: set of initial states
-- last line: set of final states
-- other lines: transitions table entries, each one is of the form:
-- (state, char viewed, set of next states)

module NFA where

  import Control.Monad

  leerFichero :: String -> IO ()
  leerFichero filename = do
                            contenidos <- readFile filename
                            putStrLn contenidos

  data NFA = NFA { intialStates :: [String]
                 , isAccepting :: String -> Bool
                 , transition  :: [String] -> Char -> [String]
                 }

  strToRow :: [String] -> [((String, Char), [String])]
  strToRow str = map crea_tupla por_espacios
    where
      crea_tupla (x:y:xs) = ((x, head y), xs)
      por_espacios = map words str

  leerNFA :: String -> IO ()
  leerNFA filename = do
                      contenidos <- readFile filename
                      --putStr "Cadena:"
                      --cadena <- getLine
                      let lineas = lines $ contenidos
                          i = words $ head lineas
                          a = (`elem` last (map words lineas))
                          nfa = NFA i a (t (strToRow (tail (init lineas))))
                      print $ t (strToRow (tail (init lineas))) ["Q0","Q1"] '#'

  t :: [((String, Char), [String])] -> [String] -> Char -> [String]
  t tab n c = n >>= (\st -> case lookup (st,c) tab of
                              Just x -> x
                              _      -> error "yo k se tio xdxd")

  --not working
  --testNFA :: NFA -> [Char] -> [String]
  --testNFA (NFA i a t) = foldM t i
```

Comment: remarks on the code (independent of your question) 1. a list is not a set (use containers:Data.Set), 2. a state is not a String (make the automaton polymorphic in the `State` type  and in the `Symbol` type) 3. if you want to do anything with these automata (besides accepting some input), then you will need the transition function reified (e.g., with containers:Data.Map)

Comment: By the way, you don't have to indent all of your code by two spaces - it's valid without indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your code so that `transition` has the type `State -> Symbol -> [State]`. This really is what NFAs have: to get your `[State] -> Symbol -> [State]` function you take the union of calls to this one. Then you will be able to use `foldM` easily.

An example:

```
import Control.Monad

type Symbol = Char
type State  = String

data NFA = NFA { initialState :: State
               , isAccepting  :: State -> Bool
               , transition   :: State -> Symbol -> [State] }

-- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Example
exampleNFA :: NFA
exampleNFA = NFA { initialState = "p"
                 , isAccepting  = (== "q")
                 , transition   = exampleTransition }

exampleTransition :: State -> Symbol -> [State]
exampleTransition "p" '0' = ["p"]
exampleTransition "p" '1' = ["p", "q"]
exampleTransition "q" '0' = []
exampleTransition "q" '1' = []

runNFA :: NFA -> String -> [State]
runNFA (NFA init _ trans) = foldM trans init

main = print $ runNFA exampleNFA "01101"
```

Comment: Still can't realize how to use foldM

Comment: I wrote a small example. You can use `foldM` directly if you have only one initial state; I think otherwise you will need to write `foldM trans =<< init`.